# Is multiplying by Ts faster than dividing by fs?

Tags: floating-point

Say fs = 1000 and Ts = 0.001. Would it be faster to compute Ts at the beginning and subsequently multiply by 0.001 instead of dividing by 1000 when computing frequency-dependent quantities?

Comment: This isn't really a signal-processing question *per se*; the answer to your question is going to depend on the characteristics of the computing platform you're using. In general, yes, multiplication is usually faster and less hardware-intensive than division.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for posting in the wrong forum

Comment: Yes. For most platforms it's faster to multiply then to divide

Comment: Presumably you're using the $T_s$ to scale coefficients.  If your sampling rate is fixed, it's faster to precompute your scaled coefficients.  I.e., in your code don't use `T_s * k_i * error`; use `k_i * error` with `k_i` appropriately scaled.

Comment: Isn't that something that one could easily test with two loops?

Comment: @M529 I guess so. Or you could write both operations one after another and compare the disassembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it makes sense to ensure that your code is logically correct, that it is numerically well-behaved, intuitive to read and tested. That is hard enough. Only when you observe that some innerloop or library call is a real hotspot, affecting the functionality of your software does it make sense to rewrite code for speed, and then you should always profile before and after.

If a constant is known compile time, the compiler may apply the inversion to substitute division for multiplication, if this is within precision constraints and runs faster for a given target. If ppssible, I would rather outsource that complexity to the compiler.

Edit:

It is not "technically the same operation". To see why, have a look at this MATLAB snippet:

```
a = single(10.0)
b = 1/a
c = 42/a
d = 42*b

c-d

ans =

  single

 -4.7684e-07
```

Since floating-point is operating with finite precision and intermediate rounding, the order of operations does matter. Depending on compiler flags, the compiler may be allowed to re-order floatingpoint arithmetic even though the result will differ to some degree.

If we look at the binary representation we see that they differ in the lsb:

```
dec2bin(typecast(c,'uint32'),32)
dec2bin(typecast(d,'uint32'),32)

ans = '01000000100001100110011001100110'
ans = '01000000100001100110011001100111'
```

-k

Comment: You pointed out something important: It depends on the compiler. Since it is technically the same operation, a good compiler would choose the best way of accomplishing it.

Comment: See edits in my answer

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out